# what is correct approach of error handling in node/express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

so this is not http failure this is basically after the success response we applied filter based on logic if certain conditions does not meet with the the response we rendered it should throw expected error. So i think added code at right place , just curious about if there is service failure this code would effect i believe it should go to catch in that case.

main.js

```
app.post('url', async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const drugPriceResponse = await fetchDrugPrice(req, externalId, tokenId, drugName);

    if (drugPriceResponse.status && drugPriceResponse.status === 500) {
      res.send(500).send(drugPriceResponse);
    } else {
     res.status(200).send({
        drugPrice: drugPriceResponse
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);

    if (e.response) {
      res.status(e.response.status).send(e.response.data);
    } else {
      res.status(500).send(defaultErrorResponse);
    }
  }
});
```

data

```
{

  "drugPrice": {

    "status": 500,

    "title": "Internal Server Error",

    "detail": "Drug prices are not valid"

  }

};
```

expected output

```
{

        "status": 500,

        "title": "Internal Server Error",

        "detail": "Drug prices are not valid"

      }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code... whats the question again?

Comment: @IsaacVidrine question is if service failed at await it would go to next line or it will go to catch because if service fails dont want to execute `if (drugPriceResponse.status && drugPriceResponse.status === 500) ` this code

Comment: If the promise is rejected it will go straight to the `catch` block